# Problem solving the max and min from an input file data

Tags: python, file, input, find, max

I am new with python and i need a little help with my python script named search_max.py.

It opens a file "xyz" format and then search for the min and max of each coord. The problem is when i do the same with an awk script i don't get the same resuts!!!

I wonder if there is a problem with the type of data or string operation or ... Can anyone help me solve this problem?

## Python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
inputfile = "peamorphe.xyz"
outputfile = "result.txt"
# open the input file
infile = open(inputfile, "r")
# read line 1 : number of atoms
atomsno = infile.readline().rstrip('\n').split(" ")
# read line 2 : name of the system
systemname = infile.readline().rstrip('\n')
# read line 3 : initialisation for min and max
temp2 = infile.readline().rstrip('\n').split(" ")
zmin = temp2[3]
zmax = temp2[3]
ymax = temp2[2]
ymin = temp2[2]
xmax = temp2[1]
xmin = temp2[1]
lineno = 3
print zmax, ymin, xmin
# read other lines
for ligne in infile.readlines():
    lineno = lineno + 1
    # extraction and strip of data spaced by " "
    data = ligne.rstrip('\n\r').split(" ")
    # Conditions for min and max
    if data[1] < xmin: 
        xmin = data[1] 
        wclxmin = lineno
    if data[1] > xmax: 
        xmax = data[1]
        wclxmax = lineno
    if data[2] < ymin: 
        ymin = data[2]
        wclymin = lineno
    if data[2] > ymax: 
        ymax = data[2]
        wclymax = lineno
    if data[3] < zmin:
        zmin = data[3]
        wclzmin = lineno
    if data[3] > zmax: 
        zmax = data[3] 
        wclzmax = lineno

# Evaluation of centers
zcenter = float(zmax)-float(zmin)
ycenter = float(ymax)-float(ymin)
xcenter = float(xmax)-float(xmin)

# open the input file
infile = open(inputfile, "r")
# read line 1 : number of atoms
atomsno = infile.readline().rstrip('\n').split(" ")
# read line 2 : name of the system
systemname = infile.readline().rstrip('\n')
# read line 3 : initialisation for min and max
temp2 = infile.readline().rstrip('\n').split(" ")
zmin = temp2[3]
zmax = temp2[3]
ymax = temp2[2]
ymin = temp2[2]
xmax = temp2[1]
xmin = temp2[1]
lineno = 3
print zmax, ymin, xmin
# read other lines
for ligne in infile.readlines():
    lineno = lineno + 1
    # extraction and strip of data spaced by " "
    data = ligne.rstrip('\n\r').split(" ")
    # Conditions for min and max
    if data[1] < xmin: 
        xmin = data[1] 
        wclxmin = lineno
    if data[1] > xmax: 
        xmax = data[1]
        wclxmax = lineno
    if data[2] < ymin: 
        ymin = data[2]
        wclymin = lineno
    if data[2] > ymax: 
        ymax = data[2]
        wclymax = lineno
    if data[3] < zmin:
        zmin = data[3]
        wclzmin = lineno
    if data[3] > zmax: 
        zmax = data[3] 
        wclzmax = lineno

# Evaluation of centers
zcenter = float(zmax)-float(zmin)
ycenter = float(ymax)-float(ymin)
xcenter = float(xmax)-float(xmin)
```

## awk script :

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# from a xyz file
BEGIN{
xmax;xmin;
zmax;zmin;
ymax;ymin;
xcent;ycent;zcent;
xcent = (xmax-xmin)/2;
ycent = (ymax-ymin)/2;
zcent = (zmax-zmin)/2;
print   "At the start of the script";
print   "xmax = " xmax "; " "xmin = " xmin "; xcent = " xcent; 
print   "ymax = " ymax "; " "ymin = " ymin "; ycent = " ycent;
print   "zmax = " zmax "; " "zmin = " zmin "; zcent = " zcent;
print   "";
}

{
if (xmax<$2) xmax = $2
if (xmin>$2) xmin = $2
if (ymax<$3) ymax = $3
if (ymin>$3) ymin = $3
if (zmax<$4) zmax = $4
if (zmin>$4) zmin = $4
}

END{
xcent = (xmax-xmin)/2;
ycent = (ymax-ymin)/2;
zcent = (zmax-zmin)/2;
print   "At the end of the script";
print   "xmax = " xmax "; " "xmin = " xmin "; xcent = " xcent; 
print   "ymax = " ymax "; " "ymin = " ymin "; ycent = " ycent;
print   "zmax = " zmax "; " "zmin = " zmin "; zcent = " zcent}
```

you can download my input file here (14 days): [peamorphe.xyz](http://transvol.sgsi.ucl.ac.be/download.php?id=a44c607b0c30fd9f)

Thank you in advance,
Exilien.

Comment: In Python, you are comparing `data[...]`, which is a string, not a number. You have to `float()` it first, otherwise `999 > 1000`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why your code does not work as expected is given by eumiro in his above comment.

There is an far easier approach for this in Python though:  Use [NumPy](https://numpy.org/).  Example code for maxima and minima of each column of your file would be

```
import numpy
a = numpy.loadtxt("peamorphe.xyz", skiprows=2, usecols=(1, 2, 3))
max_xyz = a.max(axis=0)
min_xyz = a.min(axis=0)
center = max_xyz - min_xyz
```

These few lines of code do everything your script does, including parsing the input file.  If you also need the indices of the maxima and minima, you can use `a.argmax()` and `a.argmin()`.

Looks quite a bit easier, don't you think?

Comment: Yeah really :). Thanks a lot. I was not aware of Numpsy :p. Thank you also eumiro for this precision.